# Is single-word "inbetween" becoming more acceptable? How far can it go?

Tags: idioms, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I get the distinct feeling that *"inbetween"* occurs increasingly often as a single word, but I'm not at all clear on why it's used more in some contexts than others.

What I can is see that in Google Books, *"are inbetween"* occurs [far less often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20in%20between,are%20inbetween&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *"are in between"*, whereas *"the inbetween"* occurs [more often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20in%20between,the%20inbetween&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *"the in between"*. What's going on?

Comment: My first thought was that "inbetween" is being used in the noun cases, and "in between" elsewhere, but clicking through some of those results, I only found one case of "are inbetween" using "inbetween" as a noun...

Comment: @Jim: I had thought the same! I think it's more a matter of the single-word form being seen as a kind of "adjective" rather than a "compound preposition", but hopefully someone else will have more to say on the matter.

Comment: The space is inaudible in speech, so it's purely a spelling problem. Words, especially function words, get compounded all the time, and spacing varies.

Comment: I'm always using inbetween as one word. I guess I'm ahead of my time!

Comment: @Matt: That it indeed a key point, imho. Is it in fact the case that **all** usages can reasonably be treated as "single concept", and will they therefore all eventually be written as a single word? Always assuming there really *is* an increasing tendency to use the single-word form, which is how it appears to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had not previously been aware of seeing it printed other than as two words, but the practice seems not to be particularly new. The OED records the hyphenated noun *in-between* as meaning ‘(a) An interval.  (b) A person who intervenes.’ The first citation is dated 1815:

> He's fallen in love with Lady Naglefort, because she's an in-between.

It’s followed a year later in Jane Austen’s ‘Emma’ by:

> Busy . . . talking and listening, and forming all these schemes in the
>   in-betweens.

As an adjective meaning ‘placed between’, it occurs first, once again hyphenated, in 1898:

> White or pale-coloured silk, with an in-between layer of chiffon.

Comment: Which is just about what one would expect. I am not sure why the OP is really excited about the discovery AD.

Comment: I understand the inclination to make it a single word specifically when it's used as a *noun* - but even among Google Books instances of **"the inbetween"**, it's mostly used adjectivally. I'm only really interested in the existence of a hyphenated form because that's usually a precursor to something becoming a single word, but in this case it doesn't seem so simple. I suspect *on average* there may be some subtle difference between usage of one/two word forms in the non-noun context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A version of the British National Corpus that I am using has no records for either ‘inbetween’ or ‘in-between’. There is, however, one instance of ‘in between’ as a noun:  ‘. . . she's opening up actually in Exeter but this is an in between . . .’

Comment: I don't know too much about how these "corpora" are managed, but might it not be that the people doing that managing have pre-decided that the single-word and hyphenated forms "don't count"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, I don't think that's the case at all. I've just looked at the full BNC and found 48 records for 'in-between'.