# What is the difference between "in-between" and "in between"?

Tags: prepositions, hyphenation

Which of the following two is correct?:

> 1. The man is sitting in between the two women

or:

> 2. The man is sitting in-between the two women.

What is the general rule?

Related but different questions: [What is the difference between "in-between" and "between"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-difference-between-in-between-and-between) and [Is single-word "inbetween" becoming more acceptable? How far can it go?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58782/is-single-word-inbetween-becoming-more-acceptable-how-far-can-it-go)

Comment: The second has a hyphen in between the two words.

Answer (score 4):

According to Merriam-Webster, '[in-between](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in-between)' is used as a noun or adjective whereas '[in between](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20between)' is an adverb or preposition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Never use dictionaries for grammar information. It's not what they're designed for!

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct form would be actually:

> The man is sitting between the two women.

So, neither. You are using `between` as a preposition here, so if you refer to the questions you gave as examples in your question, you should use just `between`.

Answer (score 0):

"Between the two women" denotes a space. If there is a space then you can be in that space; you can be in "between the two women". "In-between" also denotes that space whereas "between" doesn't.

In-between can work by implied reference but "between" cannot. Consider "*Two women are sitting at either end of a bench for four*". You wouldn't say "*The man is sitting **between***" but you could say that he's "*sitting **between them***" or you could say "*The man is sitting **in-between***".

Answer (score 0):

I feel that between is the whole example including the outer layer due to show its starting and ending point

And +++++ in/- between +++++   is what is excluding the starting and ending point. Not know what the difference in the hyphen resembles.

I feel if that if its between something how would you describe the start and end of the example except for using it as a alternative metephor. It is a connotes. The tricky meangs of words in the english language.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand what you're saying here. For example, what are the + and / signs in the second paragraph supposed to represent? Also "connotes" is a verb not a noun, so you can't say something is a connotes.